# Массово задать атрибуты картинок в контенте

Tags: sql, wordpress

Сайт на WP картинки в записях вставлены в контент. Нужно для всех записей каждому изображению добавить alt и title по принципу: Название записи этап 1, Название записи этап 2, Название записи этап 3...

Я сейчас вижу 3 варианта:

1) Существующий плагин (поиск чего-то подходящего не дал)
2) Обработка при выводе
3) Изменить через SQL запрос в таблице (с запросами сталкиваюсь редко поэтому не представляю есть ли там аналог цикла)

Можете натолкнуть на более верный/простой вариант?

Comment: По-разному можно сделать. Сколько картинок примерно?

Comment: Больше 1000 в записях

Comment: Есть масса плагов с таким функционалом. Искать как-то  так https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/seo+image/ А базу никого не лезь, если стойкого желания поломать сайт

Comment: Имхо, ответ от @Krya рабочее решение в вашем случае

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не менял в базе, а менял через хук wp_get_attachment_image_attributes

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'filter_function_name_2256', 10, 3 );
function filter_function_name_2256( $attr, $attachment, $size ){
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $attr['alt']  = get_the_title();
        $attr['title'] = get_the_title();
    }       

    return $attr;
}
```

https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes

Comment: такой вариант просто подставит название поста. Загвоздка в том что каждой фотографии нужно добавить порядковый номер внутри записи

Comment: Перед ф-циями global $counter; $counter = 1;. Внутри ф-уции global $counter - это порядковый номер, но после определение аттрибутов $counter++;